# Firebase: Which nodes are read with forEach function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm reading some data from Firebase Realtime database. I only need the key (serial.key) of the node, however, I have noticed that logging serial.val() returns all nodes under that node, which would cost me a lot in reads. So, my question is whether my code (the reference) always also reads the values or if I use the command serial.key only the key?

```
    const serialRef = db.ref("Devices")
serialRef.once('value', (serials)=>{
  serials.forEach((serial)=>{
    console.log(serial.key)
    //console.log(serial.val()) -->Are these nodes downloaded automatically with the reference?
  })
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your query fetches the complete `Devices` node and you cannot only fetch the children keys. I'm not completely sure about how your database is structured but you should avoid using a single node to store data and create deep nodes.

After fetching the data if you need keys then you can use `Object.keys()`:

```js
const devices = snapshot.val()
const keys = Object.keys(devices)
// Array of keys of all children of devices.
```

---

You can create a separate node "deviceIDs" and store only IDs of those new devices (child keys) in that node. So that node will contain only the IDs and not complete data which will save bandwidth usage.

Update: The [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-param-shallow) does allow shallow queries. If that suits your needs then you can try using that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! May I also ask whether this command: serialRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(1) will download all nodes before returning the last one, or does it only download the last?

Comment: @Nina it will get the last one only.